# Adding numbers forth column of first file to second file using awk.

Tags: awk

Hoping somebody can help me with this task. I have two infiles,

File1

```
# name                  length  av.qual #-reads mx.cov. av.cov  GC% CnIUPAC CnFunny CnN CnX CnGap   CnNoCov
10-1_rep_c1             1406    80  8017    4637    1641.26 31.98   1   0   4   0   7   0
10-1_rep_c2             832 80  1641    1462    557.34  32.13   1   0   0   0   5   0
10-1_rep_c3             1284    83  4674    2338    1040.80 24.75   7   0   0   0   8   0
10-1_rep_c4             750 83  2335    2017    886.31  24.73   2   0   0   0   3   0
10-1_rep_c5             1180    78  2326    1486    572.51  19.76   1   0   0   0   7   0
```

File2

```
>10-1_rep_c1
ttttttttttttttacaataaaatgcrccattattcctttcgtactaaacaatgccttat
ggccaccagatagaaaccaatctgactcacgtcgattttaactcaaatcatgtaaaattc
>10-1_rep_c2
aacagcagaattaatattgttcacaggtttttataaaacgacctattaatgaatttccat
cccctaaaaatggtcggcttacttgatgtaaccaccccctctagttaataataattgtat
>10-1_rep_c3
aattataaaaagaatttttaaagcataaattattagtaattttaagagaaattaaaggta
ttataaaagagtaatagtactgacaaggaaaaacttttatataaaaaaaagaaaatttaa
```

The outfile I would like to have is,

```
>10-1_rep_c1_8017
ttttttttttttttacaataaaatgcrccattattcctttcgtactaaacaatgccttat
ggccaccagatagaaaccaatctgactcacgtcgattttaactcaaatcatgtaaaattc
>10-1_rep_c2_1641
aacagcagaattaatattgttcacaggtttttataaaacgacctattaatgaatttccat
cccctaaaaatggtcggcttacttgatgtaaccaccccctctagttaataataattgtat
>10-1_rep_c3_4674
aattataaaaagaatttttaaagcataaattattagtaattttaagagaaattaaaggta
ttataaaagagtaatagtactgacaaggaaaaacttttatataaaaaaaagaaaatttaa
```

So the fourth column of the first file appended onto the second file header of each DNA sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[">"$1]="_"$4;next}{print $0a[$0]}' File1 File2
```

Answer (score 1):

try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$4;next} ($2 in a){print $2"_"a[$2];next} 1' file1 FS=">" file2
```

**Explanation:** So checking here first condition `FNR==NR`(which will be only TRUE when first file named file1 is being read, because FNR and NR both represent the number of lines in a Input_file only difference between them is NR's value will be keep on increasing till all files being read and FNR's value will be RESET each time when a new Input_file start to get read.), so in first file reading time creating an array named a whose index is $1 and value is $4(as per your ask), now mentioning next keyword which will make sure cursor shouldn't go further and it will skip all further statements then.
Now checking condition where checking if $2 of file2(whose field separator I have set as > to remove it from mix, **NOTE: we could set field separators differently for different Input_files**).

So if it is present then print 2nd field of Input_file file2 and "_" then array a's value whose index is $2 of file2, then mentioning next to skip further statements. Now mentioning 1 will be printing the lines(apart from whose $2 comes in array a as index, so awk works on method like condition then action. If any condition is TRUE then some action should happen. Here condition is TRUE by mentioning 1 and action is Not defined so by default print will happen, print of current line of file2).

Then mentioning the Input_file1 name as file1. After that mentioning the FS(field separator's value) to ">"(explained above too). After that mentioning the second Input_file as file2 too then.